# Помогите написать цикл из значений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая структура ссылок:

```
<a href="" class="data-link" data-result="d,a"></a>
<a href="" class="data-link" data-result="d,a,c,d,4,5"></a>
<a href="" class="data-link" data-result="a"></a>
<a href="" class="data-link" data-result="v"></a>
<a href="" class="data-link" data-result="g"></a>
```

Мне нужно вывести список с количеством букв. То есть. Если в data-result - а встречается 10 раз, то нужно вывести на страницу a = 10, b = 15, c = 13, ну и так далее. Чет у меня не получается. Пытался использовать split(","), но не могу правильно написать цикл. Помогите кому не сложно.

Пытался сделать так:

```
    $(".data-link").each(function() {
    var variant = $(this).data("result").split(',');

    if($(".debug").find(".variant-"+variant[0]).length < 1) {
        $(".debug").append("<span class='variant-"+variant[0]+"'>"+variant[0]+" = <span>0</span></span><br>");
    }

    if($(".debug").find(".variant-"+variant[1]).length < 1 && variant[1] != null) {
        $(".debug").append("<span class='variant-"+variant[1]+"'>"+variant[1]+" = <span>0</span></span><br>");
    }

    if($(".debug").find(".variant-"+variant[2]).length < 1 && variant[2] != null) {
        $(".debug").append("<span class='variant-"+variant[2]+"'>"+variant[2]+" = <span>0</span></span><br>");
    }

    if($(".debug").find(".variant-"+variant[3]).length < 1 && variant[3] != null) {
        $(".debug").append("<span class='variant-"+variant[3]+"'>"+variant[3]+" = <span>0</span></span><br>");
    }


});
```

Но тогда придеться создавать if для кажой комы :(

Comment: что за `$(".debug")`, что ищется внутри него `find(".variant-"+variant[0])`? как это вообще связано с задачей посчитать количество в _data-result_?

Comment: и приведите пример ожидаемого вывода для разметки которая в посте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо сделать один массив со всеми значениями из `data-result`, я сделал это в переменной `chars`. Затем пробежаться по этому массиву и посчитать количество одинаковых значений, записывая результат в объект `counts`.

Остается только написать цикл по объекту `counts` для вывод данных на странице.

```
var chars = [], counts = {};
$(".data-link").each(function() {
  chars = chars.concat($(this).data("result").split(','));
})

for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
  if(!counts.hasOwnProperty(chars[i])) {
    counts[chars[i]] = 1;
  } else {
    counts[chars[i]]++;
  }
}

console.log(counts)
Object {4: 1, 5: 1, d: 3, a: 3, c: 1, v: 1, g: 1}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @ЕвгенийВенеград, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).